# How to slice ndarray after hstacking , back to original pieces

Tags: python, numpy, slice

Hi i would like to recover two pieces of a composite numpy array that was made by stacking two smaller arrays. i need the slicing for each peice, iyou could help me.

i have two ndarrays that i hastacked on to each other

```
frame = np.hstack([thought1,pix])
```

shape for pix and thought1 is equal to (1080, 1920, 3)
for both of them

after stacking shape of frame is (1080, 3840, 3)
i want to recover thought1 and pix from frame by slicing
it

```
frame = np.hstack([thought1,pix])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'inverse' of np.hstack would be [np.hsplit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hsplit.html)

```py
thought1, pix = np.hsplit(np.hstack([thought1,pix]), [thought1.shape[1]])
```

Comment: Thankyou, which peice will that give me?

Comment: I also have the following problem `data2= np.concatenate((data,thoughtsetSound ),-1) data.shape=(1,2) and thoughtsetSound.shape=(1,1000) so data2.shape=(1,1002)` and i would like to recover both data and thoughtsetSound. Please.